# Можно ли скриптом вернуть текст?

Tags: html, perl

Здравствуйте!
Есть HTML код, например

```
[font color="#ff0000"]...[/font]
```

и скрипт на `Perl`.Мне нужно вместо "..." подставить цифры обратившись к скрипту, который их вернет.
Собственно два вопроса:Как скриптом на `Perl` просто вернуть цифры, 1.23 например. Что то вроде return "1.23";И как к скрипту обратится из `html`?Например мне нужно поставить определенную картинку на странице. Я делаю в скрипте:

```
print "Location: <путь к моей картинке>\n\n";
```

и в html вызываю так:

```
[img src=".../скрипт.cgi?<здесь какие то параметры>"]
```

в результате на странице появляется картинка.А мне нужно вставить цифры, текст, т.е. как в примере в начале:

```
[font color="#ff0000"]как здесь вызвать скрипт?[/font]
```

чтобы на странице получилось

```
[font color="#ff0000"]1.23[/font]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Использование SSI](http://stepbystep.htmlbook.ru/?id=42)

```
Статью прочитало, чел.: <!--#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/counter.cgi?id=5"-->
```

вот тут как раз ответ на ваш вопрос. Но с распространением фреймворков, я вижу включения через ssi крайне редко (раньше это был чуть ли не единственный вариант вставить результаты выполнения скрипта).

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы не заморачивались и начинали работать с какими-то простыми фреймворками типа Dancer или Mojolicious::Lite, по ним есть куча документации, отличные примеры и даже какие-то подкасты. На пример: http://mojocasts.com/PS: Такие вопросы лучше задавать в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/